# Posting java code on wordpress.com. Highlight issues and lost indentation

Tags: java, wordpress, syntax-highlighting, code-formatting, wordpress.com

I am trying to post some java code snippets on wordpress.com using the following tags as suggested here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

[sourcecode language="java"]
...
[/sourcecode]

But all the indentation is lost and the comments doesn't get highlighted properly. The codes were copied from Eclipse.

You can see the problem here: http://lifelearner168.wordpress.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try posting this code and tell me what it does:

```
        ​//indentation test
            //further indentation​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: The first one shows the indentation correctly! What is the difference between the two?

Thanks

Comment: between the 1st and 2nd line you mean? or this example and pasting on jsfizzle?

Comment: I pasted your code in wordpress.com. The first line shows the indetation correctly. The indentation in the second line is lost. Can you please tell why the first line works? Many thanks!

Comment: I got it. It seems indentation is lost if I paste the code under the "Visual" view but if I paster the code under "HTML" view. The indentation is working. 

But I still have no idea why the comments are not working properly. At the moment I just have to use [sourcecode language="javascript"] instead of [sourcecode language="java"]. Atleast it highlights the comments properly.

Answer (score 0):

Paste it in the JavaScript text area here: http://jsfiddle.net/ to make sure the indentation is in a web compatible format and then copy it from the textarea again and paste it in the wordpress posting text area. Eclipse probably has a weird indentation method.

I looked at the source of the page and it didn't have any indentation, so it has to be something in the posting process on wordpress rather than a problem with the way it is displaying on the page when it is queried. (ignore this if it doesn't make any sense..)

Comment: When I paste the code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and worepress.com , I can see the indentation. But as soon as I press publish, all the indentations are gone.

Answer (score 0):

As user1296058 mentioned, if you use [sourcecode language="javascript"] it will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked for me :

```
[code language="java"]
//YOUR CODE
[/code]
```